# Were Ninny and Idgie the same person?

Tags: fried-green-tomatoes

In the movie [Fried Green Tomatoes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101921/?ref_=sr_1) a story is told to an unhappy house wife about two women (Idgie and Ruth) and their adventures. The elderly woman telling the story is named Ninny Threadgoode. One of the principal characters is named Idgie Threadgoode. Are they the same person?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a fairly common misconception with the movie. In the book, Fried Green Tomatoes at the Whistle Stop Cafe, it is absolutely clear that the two are separate characters. In fact, if I remember correctly, they are even in some of the same scenes. In the movie however, it is not as apparent. According to the film synopsis on Wikipedia, Ninny describes Idgie as her sister in law. Which would fit with the book, however I don't recall it ever being that specific in the movie. Another large part of the book that was played down in the film is the romantic relationship between Idgie and Ruth.

Answer (score 1):

The implication that **Ninny** and **Idgie** are the same person, therefore it is impossible based on several other points in the film.

The book makes it clear that Ninny and Idgie are different people.

Evelyn takes Ninny out of the nursing home to go live with her and they are visiting the cemetary when she finds the jar of honey and the note on **Ruth's** tombstone.

Comment: The first part of this answer is a sentence fragment.

Comment: The cemetery scene only proves that Ruth is dead, not Idgie. The jar of honey is left on Ruth's grave, not Idgies. It shows no headstone for Idgie. Therefore Idgie is still alive in the cemetery scene.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same person.  Early in the movie Ninny tells Evelyn that she had married Idgie's brother, Cleo.

Comment: The movie takes place in Alabama, though.